# web scraping selenium dataframe sending nice email html table with icons or images inside

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium

I have this code to build the the table to be sent later inline html email:

```
coin_logo = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody[1]/tr/td[3]/a/div/img')
coin_name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody[1]/tr/td[3]/a/div/div/p')
coin_simbol = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody[1]/tr/td[3]/a/div/div/div/p')
coin_price = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody[1]/tr/td[4]')
hour_move = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody[1]/tr/td[5]')
day_move = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody[1]/tr/td[6]')
trade_volume = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody[1]/tr/td[8]')
blockchain = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody[1]/tr/td[9]')
added_ago = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody[1]/tr/td[10]')

coin_added = []

while i <= j:
    temporary_data = {
        'Logo': coin_logo[i].get_attribute('src'),
        'Coin name': coin_name[i].text,
        'Simbol': coin_simbol[i].text,
        'Price': coin_price[i].text,
        '1h': hour_move[i].text,
        '24h': day_move[i].text,
        'volume': trade_volume[i].text,
        'Blockchain': blockchain[i].text,
        'Added': added_ago[i].text
        }
    coin_added.append(temporary_data)
    i += 1

df_data=pd.DataFrame(coin_added)
```

The line `'Logo': coin_logo[i].get_attribute('src')` suppose to show a small icon but instead it shows the link to it, how to show the icon or a small image png?

Answer (score 0):

### HTML src Attribute

The [*src*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_src.asp) attribute specifies the location (URL) of the external resource.

So when you:

```
'Logo': coin_logo[i].get_attribute('src')
```

will always collect the `URL`s i.e. the links to the images only.

To download the actual images, you may have to use [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests)

Comment: And I can use variable and how to implement in the html table I’m sending in email? Can you please give example?